# Cheapest flight for range of days with Amadeus API

Tags: python, amadeus

I am building an application to find the optimal time to fly using amadeus' API, however, the flight offers API seems to be only able to give me flight prices for a single day. The nature of my application is that for a single client, I am interested in the cheapest flight per day across a given span of dates.

For example, if a client says "what is the cheapest week to travel to XYZ airport in the next six months?" I am only interested in the cheapest flight for each day during that six month span. Additionally, 6(months)x30(days)x2(outgoing and returning flight) = 360 calls to the API for only only one client? seems like a lot.

Is there any way for me to ask for more information per call than what I am doing in the code below? I really need to reduce the number of calls drastically for my software to be usable. I expect to be inquiring about 1000s of flights per day in short bursts and right now I am already having issues with the requests per 100ms limit. I am threading requests to save time right now but I have to throttle my own speed quite a lot in order to keep the API requests working.

Any help would be really appreciated, even if the best advice is to find a new API.

```
try:
    response = amadeus.shopping.flight_offers_search.get(
        originLocationCode= origin_airport,
        destinationLocationCode=destination_airport, # self explanatory
        departureDate='2022-11-01',
        adults=1
        )

    df = pd.DataFrame(response.data)
    df.to_csv('raw_flight_data.csv', index=False) 

except ResponseError as error:
    print(error)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Owen, are you testing the app in Test environment? Do you have a production Account?

Comment: Here, you can see the concurrency limits: https://developers.amadeus.com/pricing#pricing-list